# Prove equality functions

Tags: calculus

Let $~~f : [1,3] \rightarrow [1,2] ~~$  be a bijective , continuous and strictly increasing function  , and let $g$ be another function such as $ ~~g: [0,+\infty[ \rightarrow \mathbb{R} ~~~~, ~~g(0) = 0 ~~$    and :

$g(x) = 2^{\textbf{-}n}f(3^{n}x) ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~/~~~~~~~~ n \in \mathbb{Z} ~~~~~~,~~~~~~ 3^{n}x \in[1,3[$

prove that : $ 2g(x) = g(3x) $

Comment: Does the given relation hold for all $\forall n \in \mathbb{Z}\,$, or for one particular integer value $n\,$?

Answer (score 1):

Since
$g(x) = 2^{-n}f(3^{n}x)
$,
$g(3x) 
= 2^{-n}f(3^{n}3x)
= 2^{-n}f(3^{n+1}x)
$.

But
$g(x) 
= 2^{-n-1}f(3^{n+1}x)
= \frac12\cdot 2^{-n}f(3^{n+1}x)
=\frac12 g(3x)
$,
so
$2 g(x) = g(3x)
$.

Comment: straight method , thanks :-)

Comment: A bit odd that, other than the functional relation itself, none of premises were used (or needed).

Comment: That occurred to me also.